# Import JSON broken Firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have exported my app JSON file and edited a name on it to test the importing function, but it is not working either on Chrome or on Edge.Also, I have found this [Google Form](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB#!topic/firebase-talk/i04GGYV_4dI) that users are complaining from the same thing as some of them say on Edge it is working but for me it's not

Tested on

- OS: Windows 10 Build 14393.rs1_release.160715-1616
- Browser: Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit), Edge Browser

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: have you check your JSON validity at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ ?

Comment: Thats work but how could the JSON file is not Valid and I just export it form the firebase and edit it with notepad++ nothing more, also the Firebase said that the file is iported succesfully

Comment: if you check it on the link @Wilik gave you, that site should tell you where you are wrong

Comment: The most common errors are the lack of quote sign for key or string value and missing commas for each child.
You can post your JSON here or upload it somewhere so we can have a look

Comment: @koceeng it but it seems the wrong is the file it self as I have edit it with notepad++

Comment: @wilik thank you, will you add you comment as an answer to let me accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before importing back to Firebase Database, make sure to check your JSON validity. You can do this at some website such as https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

The most common errors are the lack of quote sign for key or string value and missing commas for each child.